# USB thermometer that works in Linux

Tags: linux, usb, temperature, sensors

I am constructing a small robot based on an embedded board running Linux.

I am looking for a USB thermometer device, which will work with the 2.6 kernel. So far I found a bunch of devices, but it's not clear whether they have Linux drivers or not (no description).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a Ubuntuforums thread for [Linux Compatible Thermometers](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=205251).
There is another even older one at [LinuxQuestions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/general-10/usb-thermometer-that-works-w-linux-286752/)

---

Here is a reference to [Brando USB Thermometer](http://usb.brando.com/prod_detail.php?prod_id=00381).
[Article reference](http://www.funponsel.com/blog/hardware-and-peripheral/temper-usb-thermometer-for-laboratorians.html) for the same (do read this through).
A derkeiler [2.6 Kernel patch thread](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Kernel/2009-01/msg08094.html) from there.
And at the end a recent posting reference: [TEMPer Temperature Sensor Linux Driver](http://relavak.wordpress.com/2009/10/17/temper-temperature-sensor-linux-driver/).